# How to add URL in grid view in ext js?

Tags: url, gridview, extjs

I want to add URL at run time in a grid view in Ext Js and clicking this URL will open a new form at another panel on same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a [`renderer`](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for your column. If your have a `url` field in your model, that would be something like this:

```
columns: [
    {
        dataIndex: 'url'
        ,text: "URL"
        ,renderer: function(value) {
            return Ext.isEmpty(value)
                ? ''
                : '<a href="' + value + '" target="_blank">' + value + '</a>';
        }
    }
    ...
]
```